# How to remove the ID part in my form html tag when using Html.Beginform helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the form helper like so:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))

}
```

My controller's action is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

When I look at my HTML, the generated form tag is:

```
<form action="/File/Upload/123123" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</form>
```

For some reason it is including the id part of my url during the get request.  How can I remove it so it is just:

```
action="/File/Upload"
```

Also just so I understand, could I change my action declaration also?

Comment: Can I ask why? You could change it to plain old HTML as a last resort.

Comment: the page the form is on has an id of 123123?

Comment: Works for me...IOW renders without ID and without change from OP's `Html.BeginForm` declaration.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that an id would show up in the url is if you had an id member of the object passed in as the 4th parameter. The one with enctype

Comment: @HaBo That's not a valid call to BeginForm. No overload has 5 parameters and FormMethod as the third one. They are using [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714(v=vs.108).aspx), which should only be passing an id if it is set in htmlAttributes.

Comment: @bdwain you are right. I rushed to comment before realizing the helper.

Comment: @DavidTansey My GET request for the form is like this `public ActionResult Upload(string id)`

Comment: you should pass in an int for the id

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to remove the `id` part.

But to answer your question, yes you can.
Here is how you do it.

Try this first based on [Html.BeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File")
{
}
```

If that doesn't work (or) still putting in the `id` value, try using this
 [Html.BeginForm(RouteValueDictionary routeValues)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "File" }, { "action", "Upload" } })
{
}
```

With that, you could point to a **totally different Controller's Action Method**.
Lets say you are on `FileController`, you can set your `Form` tag to POST to another controller's action method.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AnotherUploadAction", "AnotherController"))
{
}
```

Even better, you can use [BeginRouteForm( ) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) if you want to reference to a Url route by name.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "My-Route-Name",
    url: "RouteUpload",
    defaults: new { controller = "AnotherClass", action = "Upload" }
);

@using(Html.BeginRouteForm("My-Route-Name"))
{
}
```

Comment: I want to remove the id part b/c then my form post doesn't map to the action method `public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)` because of the id I'm guessing.

Comment: So my answer should work then. It removes the `id` part, and like you requested it can post to a different controller's action method as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the `Id` from being included in the form action, you can use the RouteValues object, but the key here is to set the `Id` to an empty string, like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", new { Id = "" }))
```

Or in your case:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "File", new { Id = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Which will generate the following form tag:

```html
<form action="/File/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>
```

Alternatively, you can remove it from the `RouteData` in the controller that renders the view (although I prefer the former, as it makes the intent clearer):

```
public ActionResult MyActionName(int id)
{
    RouteData.Values.Remove("Id");

    return View();
}
```